# How to create multiple policies for multiple iam roles

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam

I'm trying to iterate through a variable that is a map(map(object)) in order to create multiple policies for multiple roles at the same time... role1 and its policies, role2 with its policies and so on.

This is applied to a module to call it and create roles and policies at the same time, with a map(object) it is possible to go through it.

However, when trying to have a policy map inside another map, I don't understand how to itearate it.

`variable.tf`

```
variable "policy" {
  description = "Policy statement example"
  type = map(map(object({
    sid       = string
    effect    = string
    actions   = list(string)
    resources = list(string)
    }))
  )
  default = {
    "key" = {
      "key" = {
        actions = [ "value" ]
        effect = "value"
        resources = [ "value" ]
        sid = "value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
main.tf
```

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example" {

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = var.policy

    content {
      sid       = lookup(statement.role1.first.value, "sid", null)
      effect    = lookup(statement.role1.first.value, "effect", null)
      actions   = lookup(statement.role1.first.value, "actions", null)
      resources = lookup(statement.role1.first.value, "resources", null)
    }
  }
}


resource "aws_iam_policy" "example" {
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.example.json
}
```

```
var.tfvars
```

```
policy = {
  role1 ={
  first = ({
    sid       = "1010"
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["EC2:*", "iam:*"]
    resources = ["*"]

  }),
  second = ({
    sid    = "2020"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "logs:*",
      "glue:*"
    ]
    resources = ["*"]

  })}
}
```

Result

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 433, in data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example":     
│  433:       sid       = lookup(statement.role1.first.value, "sid", null)
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "role1".
```

The same error is for effect, actions, resources..

Comment: I think it's a bit different. Instead of `statement.role1.first.value`, it should be `statement.value.role1.first`.

Comment: Actually, I don't think you need the key at all, i.e., `role1` is probably not required.

Comment: @MarkoE i I have changed the value that I am sending to                                                   `policy = [
    rol1 = {
      key = {
        actions   = ["value"]
        effect    = "value"
        resources = ["value"]
        sid       = "value"
      }
    }
]                                                                                                                                       ` The given value is not suitable .. map of map of object required.